# How to prove that $ ||L|| = sup\{|L(h)| : h \in H $ and $ ||h|| = 1\}$ in Hilbert space $ H $?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $ L $ be continuous functional defined on Hilbert space $ H $. $ ||L|| $ is defined as
 $ ||L|| = sup\{|L(h)| : h \in H $ and $ ||h|| \leq 1\}$

How to prove that $ ||L|| = sup\{|L(h)| : h \in H $ and $ ||h|| = 1\}$ in Hilbert space $ H $ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's obvious that $$\sup\{|L(h)|:h\in H,\|h\|=1\}\le \sup\{|L(h)|:h\in H,\|h\|\le 1\}.$$

For $0<\|h\|<1$, since $L$ is a functional
$$|L(h)|=\|h\|\cdot \left|L\left(\frac{h}{\|h\|}\right)\right|\color{red}{\le \left|L\left(\frac{h}{\|h\|}\right)\right|}.$$
Note that $\frac{h}{\|h\|}$ has norm $1$, so
$$\sup\{|L(h)|:h\in H,\|h\|\le 1\}\le \sup \{|L(h)|:h\in H,\|h\|=1\}.$$

Comment: I have two questions: 1.  Why does $|L(h)| = ||h||* \left |L \left ( \dfrac{h}{||h||} \right ) \right |$?  2.  From the equality, we get that $\sup{ \{ |L(h) | : h \in H. ||h|| \leq 1 \} } = \sup{ \{ ||h||* \left |L \left ( \dfrac{h}{||h||} \right ) \right | : h \in H. ||h|| \leq 1 \} }$, but how does the last inequality follow?

Comment: 1. $L$ is a functional, hence linear. Now treat $\|h\|$ as a number $a$: $L(h)=aL(\frac{h}{a})$.

Comment: 2. See the edited red part.